# Unable to modify value of a nested property in PS custom object

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject

I have a PS custom object:

```
TourCode           : s
TournamentNumber   : 524
TournamentName     : Mitsubishi Electric Championship at Hualalai
EnvironmentType    : PGA Tour
TournamentRootPath : /mitsubishi-electric-championship-at-hualalai
SValues            : {@{S1=championstour; S2=tournaments; S3=mitsubishi-electric-championship-at; S4=}}
```

I can easily modify values of the top level properties like TourCode or TournamentName:

```
PS C:\Users\yuriy> $testTournament.TourCode = 'r'

PS C:\Users\yuriy> $testTournament

TourCode           : r
TournamentNumber   : 524
TournamentName     : Mitsubishi Electric Championship at Hualalai
EnvironmentType    : PGA Tour
TournamentRootPath : /mitsubishi-electric-championship-at-hualalai
SValues            : {@{S1=championstour; S2=tournaments; S3=mitsubishi-electric-championship-at; S4=}}
```

But I'm stuck getting strange error message when trying to modify properties S1, S2, S4, or S4 within SValues property:

```
PS C:\Users\yuriy> $testTournament.SValues.S3 = 'newvalue'
The property 'S3' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:1
+ $testTournament.SValues.S3 = 'newvalue'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Why is it saying it cannot find the property? I can get its value easily by referring to it like this:

```
PS C:\Users\yuriy> $testTournament.SValues.S3
mitsubishi-electric-championship-at
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPD: Output of **gm -i $testTournament.SValues** is on screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr65o.png
JSON fragment is on screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/srlms.png (similar data)
The JSON file is read and converted using this code:

```
$testData = Get-Content -Raw -Path "Test Data.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Then $testTournament is created:

```
$testTournament = $testData.Tournaments | Get-Random
```

Comment: The output of `SValues` looks strange to me. Show us the output of `gm -i $testTournament.SValues`

Comment: I'm starting to suspect that `SValues` is a `[String]`. If you can also show the code that created `$testTournament` that would be very useful.

Comment: How about `$($testTournament.SValues).S3 = 'newvalue'` or `$testTournament.SValues[0].S3 = 'newvalue'`?

Comment: @briantist, $testTournament was created by filtering out a list of objects by ConvertFrom-Json cmdlet.

Comment: @YMM, show the code itself and the source JSON, and show the `gm` output. Edit it all into your question.

Comment: @briantist, I updated my question with screenshots. The JSON fragment contains data for the different tournament, but the structure is the same.

Comment: @YMM first, you should edit them in as text. If they really had to be screenshots (they don't) you could embed them. Second, you can see from the output that `SValues` is an array, so PetSerAl's second suggestion is likely the solution.

Comment: @PetSerAl, thank you! $($testTournament.SValues).S3 = 'newvalue'  worked like a charm!